# variable referenced before assignment: Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, raspberry-pi3, azure-iot-hub

I'm trying to get data from raspberry pi 3 to Azure

The script reads data from Raspberry Pi3, which is connect via bluetooth to sensors and takes several values.
Unfortunately i am getting an error, when I run it

> "local variable 'temperature' referenced before assignment"

```
def iothub_client_sample_run():
    msgs=[]

    for address, name in list(devices.items()):
    try:
        client = iothub_client_init()

        if client.protocol == IoTHubTransportProvider.MQTT & (name == "Flower care"):
       msg_txt_formatted = MSG_TXT % (
          temperature,
            sunlight,
            moisture,
            fertility)

            message = IoTHubMessage(msg_txt_formatted)
                # optional: assign ids
       message.temperature_id = "%d" % temperature

       client.send_event_async(message, send_confirmation_callback, devices.items())
       print ( "IoTHubClient.send_event_async accepted message {} for transmission to IoT Hub.".format(devices.items()) )
       return msgs      
while 1:
msgs=iothub_client_sample_run()
for msg in msgs:
print msg['topic']
print msg['payload']
(result, mid)=mqttc.publish(msg['topic'],msg['payload'])
print ( "Send status: %s" % status )
        time.sleep(10)
mqttc.disconnect()

except IoTHubError as iothub_error:
        print ( "Unexpected error %s from IoTHub" % iothub_error )
       return
except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print ( "IoTHubClient sample stopped" )
    print_last_message_time(client)
```

Comment: Show the full traceback please

Comment: Fix your formatting. And your error is pretty clear - you're trying to use the variable 'temperature' before the variable was assigned a value i.e temperature = 'x'.. This could be due to your try: statement, but we wouldnt know because of formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message here is pretty clear.

Remember that Python reads and executes code one line at a time so if you have a variable stated after the function that uses it then it is going to throw an error. Juggle your code around to put your variables before they are called and you shouldn't have any problems with this error again.